# Display HTML5 DateTime-local base on User's Locale/Culture

Tags: javascript, html, locale, cultureinfo

How to display the value of this base on user's locale/culture?

Right now it displaying US  format (mm/dd/yy) and I need UK format (dd/mm/yy).

I would also like to display base on thes user's locale format  or detect where's the user's locale.

Something like the javascript toLocaleString().

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="">
```

Comment: But then you still have the issue of misidentified locations and assuming that location is a reliable indicator of how users want dates presented. Far better to either allow users to configure the format themselves, or (best of all) write dates in an unambiguous format (e.g. 01-Jun-2014 or 2014-06-01).

Comment: Yeah that was im thinking of, allow users to configure the format themselves. But at the moment, I need to just show the user en-UK culture in the input field. Is there a way I can force it?

Comment: No, but you can easily create a string in the required format though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported by browser yet. See following post.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/08/HTML5-Input-typedate-Formatting-Issues.

So you need to manage it via server side code for example If you want to do it with ASP.NET here is the post which will help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882561(v=vs.110).aspx

For JavaScript, you need to use tolocalstring as you have mentioned in your question.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

Comment: *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent and for many browsers is more or less equivalent to the default *toString*, it doesn't change the order of day/month or month/day at all in many cases (though it does tend to use the system language for the names of days and months, which is nice).

Comment: Yes the another options I said is to format your string from server side code. I think that is best way because you don't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.isBritish=(function(){
    return new Date('12/6/2009').getMonth()===5;
})();
```

Handy for setting up the order of inputs and date displays, anyway.

Comment: The result of *Date.parse* for non–ISO 8601 strings is entirely implementation dependant, and inconsistent even for ISO 8601 strings. In which browser is parsing of strings by *Date.parse* based on system language settings or location (as you infer)?

Comment: Oh, and the result of `Date.parse('2/6/2009')` will, in most browsers, be a UTC time value for a **local** time of 2009-02-06T00:00:00 (some may decide on 2009-06-02), and therefore different for users in different time zones. `1243915200000` is equivalent to 2009-06-02T04:00:00.000Z, indicating that you are in a timezone of UTC-04:00 (east coast USA, Atlantic Standard Time?).